# What is the difference between ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent) and startforegroundservice(intent)?

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

As the question title asks, I would like to know what their differences are as documentation is not very clear if they actually have differences.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ContextCompat` is utitility class for compatibility purposes.

`context.startForegroundService` was introduced in Android Oreo(API 26) and is new correct way to start a foreground service. Before Android Oreo you had to just call `startService` and thats what `ContextCompat.startForegroundService` does. After API 26 it calls `context.startForegroundService` or calls `context.startService` otherwise.

Code from `ContextCompat` API 27 sources.

```
/**
     * startForegroundService() was introduced in O, just call startService
     * for before O.
     *
     * @param context Context to start Service from.
     * @param intent The description of the Service to start.
     *
     * @see Context#startForegeroundService()
     * @see Context#startService()
     */
    public static void startForegroundService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            context.startForegroundService(intent);
        } else {
            // Pre-O behavior.
            context.startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just would like to know if there is difference in calling foreground service as         ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(context, myservice.class)); instead of startForegroundService(new Intent(Context, myservice.class)); It seems from API 27 source, the first way is the correct way to call startforeground service?

Comment: Yes, you want to compatible while using the latest api recommendations