# How was the source code of startService() modified to recognize if it was called from background?

Tags: android, android-source

Since about Android 9 it throws an *IllegalStateException* if `startService()` was called from the **background**. I see this exception many times in my developer console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1666)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1611)
```

In these cases, Google recommends to call `startForegroundService()` and within 5 seconds `startForeground()`, instead. [See "Background execution limits"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all).

Anyway, calling `startService()` from **foreground** is perfectly ok. Now, I wonder how exactly Android recognizes/decides that an app is in the foreground to not wrongly throwing an *IllegalStateException*?

I was starting to dig the source code of Android9/10 and comparing it with 8/7 to discover how `startService()` was modified to recognize if it was called from foreground/background. But I'm convinced that many developers before me did this already, and I would be happy if they'd give an answer.

Comment: did you check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938000/what-is-the-difference-between-contextcompat-startforegroundservicecontext-int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this link into Android's soure code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#8432) we find `getAppStartModeLocked()`:

```
int getAppStartModeLocked(int uid, String packageName, int packageTargetSdk,
        int callingPid, boolean alwaysRestrict, boolean disabledOnly) {
    UidRecord uidRec = mActiveUids.get(uid);
    if (DEBUG_BACKGROUND_CHECK) Slog.d(TAG, "checkAllowBackground: uid=" + uid + " pkg="
            + packageName + " rec=" + uidRec + " always=" + alwaysRestrict + " idle="
            + (uidRec != null ? uidRec.idle : false));
    if (uidRec == null || alwaysRestrict || uidRec.idle) {
        boolean ephemeral;
        if (uidRec == null) {
            ephemeral = getPackageManagerInternalLocked().isPackageEphemeral(
                    UserHandle.getUserId(uid), packageName);
        } else {
            ephemeral = uidRec.ephemeral;
        }
        if (ephemeral) {
            // We are hard-core about ephemeral apps not running in the background.
            return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_DISABLED;
        } else {
            if (disabledOnly) {
                // The caller is only interested in whether app starts are completely
                // disabled for the given package (that is, it is an instant app).  So
                // we don't need to go further, which is all just seeing if we should
                // apply a "delayed" mode for a regular app.
                return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_NORMAL;
            }
            final int startMode = (alwaysRestrict)
                    ? appRestrictedInBackgroundLocked(uid, packageName, packageTargetSdk)
                    : appServicesRestrictedInBackgroundLocked(uid, packageName,
                            packageTargetSdk);
            if (DEBUG_BACKGROUND_CHECK) Slog.d(TAG, "checkAllowBackground: uid=" + uid
                    + " pkg=" + packageName + " startMode=" + startMode
                    + " onwhitelist=" + isOnDeviceIdleWhitelistLocked(uid));
            if (startMode == ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_DELAYED) {
                // This is an old app that has been forced into a "compatible as possible"
                // mode of background check.  To increase compatibility, we will allow other
                // foreground apps to cause its services to start.
                if (callingPid >= 0) {
                    ProcessRecord proc;
                    synchronized (mPidsSelfLocked) {
                        proc = mPidsSelfLocked.get(callingPid);
                    }
                    if (proc != null &&
                            !ActivityManager.isProcStateBackground(proc.curProcState)) {
                        // Whoever is instigating this is in the foreground, so we will allow it
                        // to go through.
                        return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_NORMAL;
                    }
                }
            }
            return startMode;
        }
    }
    return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_NORMAL;
}
```

And the method `appRestrictedInBackgroundLocked()` (which is also called from `appServicesRestrictedInBackgroundLocked()` as fallback) decides about the `startMode`:

```
// Unified app-op and target sdk check
int appRestrictedInBackgroundLocked(int uid, String packageName, int packageTargetSdk) {
    // Apps that target O+ are always subject to background check
    if (packageTargetSdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (DEBUG_BACKGROUND_CHECK) {
            Slog.i(TAG, "App " + uid + "/" + packageName + " targets O+, restricted");
        }
        return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_DELAYED_RIGID;
    }
    // ...and legacy apps get an AppOp check
    int appop = mAppOpsService.noteOperation(AppOpsManager.OP_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND,
            uid, packageName);
    if (DEBUG_BACKGROUND_CHECK) {
        Slog.i(TAG, "Legacy app " + uid + "/" + packageName + " bg appop " + appop);
    }
    switch (appop) {
        case AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED:
            return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_NORMAL;
        case AppOpsManager.MODE_IGNORED:
            return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_DELAYED;
        default:
            return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_DELAYED_RIGID;
    }
}
```

But the final decision about foreground or background is done in `ActivityManager.isProcStateBackground(uidRec.setProcState)`:

```
/** @hide Should this process state be considered a background state? */
public static final boolean isProcStateBackground(int procState) {
    return procState >= PROCESS_STATE_TRANSIENT_BACKGROUND;
}
```

So, this section of the first method here gets the current state of foreground or background:

```
                ProcessRecord proc;
                synchronized (mPidsSelfLocked) {
                    proc = mPidsSelfLocked.get(callingPid);
                }
```

Answer (score 5):

In AOSP10 (10.0.0_r25):

Server side:

in startServiceLocked from frameworks\base\services\core\java\com\android\server\am\ActiveServices.java:

```
        // Before going further -- if this app is not allowed to start services in the
        // background, then at this point we aren't going to let it period.
        final int allowed = mAm.getAppStartModeLocked(r.appInfo.uid, r.packageName,
                r.appInfo.targetSdkVersion, callingPid, false, false, forcedStandby);
        if (allowed != ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_NORMAL) {
            Slog.w(TAG, "Background start not allowed: service "
                    + service + " to " + r.shortInstanceName
                    + " from pid=" + callingPid + " uid=" + callingUid
                    + " pkg=" + callingPackage + " startFg?=" + fgRequired);
            ......
            // This app knows it is in the new model where this operation is not
            // allowed, so tell it what has happened.
            UidRecord uidRec = mAm.mProcessList.getUidRecordLocked(r.appInfo.uid);
            return new ComponentName("?", "app is in background uid " + uidRec);
        }
```

Then in client side:

in ContextImpl.java as your log:

```
            else if (cn.getPackageName().equals("?")) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Not allowed to start service " + service + ": " + cn.getClassName());
            }
```

Comment: This was helpful. So `getAppStartModeLocked()` decides. But how?

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in following case, it will be allowed to started from background.

1. The app is persistent. Only the prebuilt system app can do this.
2. The app is not [idle](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java;l=18385). When the app process is in [background](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java;l=745) for a certain time, it will be set idle.
3. The app is idle but in an whitelist. [backgroundWhitelistUid](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java;l=8193). Only the app with system uid can add apps to this list.