# Android 10 BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast not received to application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have to run the service using BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast but while the Android 10 device is booting I get the following warning.

```
system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x400010 } to com.rahul.http/.BootReceiver
```

Mainifest:

```
 <service
        android:name=".HttpUpdateService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="true">
        
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:exported="true"

        >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I have also added permission for receiving boot_complete broadcast.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

I don't have any activity in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add add `android:directBootAware` to your `<receiver`, as in [DOC](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot#run)s

Comment: I tried that also.  As per doc It is for android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: Suppose If I add an activity and I open It. After that Reboot the device then My app received these broadcasts.

Comment: still add this line for completeness... afaik some broadcasts, permissions and other manifest-declared components will work only after first app run. hard to achieve without an `Activity`...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following attribute in your application tag in Manifest :
`android:directBootAware="true"`

Answer (score 0):

When you received an intent on Broadcast receiver you have to add the check if your application target below the Android O version. Something like this:
if app build version greater than android O than you must called **startForegroundService** method with provided intent. otherwise you just called the method **startService** with provided intent.

Comment: problem isn't related to `Service` at all, only running/receiving a broadcast, which should, but isn't happening (`onReceive` not called at all, can't run anything). btw. there is no need for `if` statement in case described by you, just use [`ContextCompat.startForegroundService`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938000/what-is-the-difference-between-contextcompat-startforegroundservicecontext-int)